# Expanding ad.fly links?

Tags: php, decode, expand, url-shortener

I was using this site via a PHP request from my own script to decode more than one ad.fly link at a time:

http://www.kassio.altervista.org/deadfly.php

But its been updated and won't handle direct PHP requests anymore. There seem to be a lot of sites out there that can decode ad.fly links. Does anyone know what the method is to do this. I'd quite like to include it in my own script rather than rely on a 3rd party to expand/decode the link?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL is likely a key in their database. Without their tools you cannot do it yourself.

This: http://pastebin.com/zFB6iUcq leads me to believe they have some API that you can access.

Comment: I think that's in reference to the API to make the shortened URL's.

Comment: That is true, but that means there's an API and they may have the capabilities to decode their URL's.